# Wordcounts line breaks in python

Tags: python, word-count

I'm trying to write a script to pull the word count of many files within a directory. I have it working fairly close to what I want, but there is one part that is throwing me off. The code so far is:

```
import glob

directory = "/Users/.../.../files/*"
output = "/Users/.../.../output.txt"

filepath = glob.glob(directory)

def wordCount(filepath):
    for file in filepath:
        name = file
        fileO = open(file, 'r')
        for line in fileO:
            sentences = 0
            sentences += line.count('.') + line.count('!') + line.count('?')

            tempwords = line.split()
            words = 0
            words += len(tempwords)

            outputO = open(output, "a")
            outputO.write("Name: " + name + "\n" + "Words: " + str(words) + "\n")

wordCount(filepath)
```

This writes the word counts to a file named "output.txt" and gives me output that looks like this:

```
Name: /Users/..../..../files/Bush1989.02.9.txt
Words: 10
Name: /Users/..../..../files/Bush1989.02.9.txt
Words: 0
Name: /Users/..../..../files/Bush1989.02.9.txt
Words: 3
Name: /Users/..../..../files/Bush1989.02.9.txt
Words: 0
Name: /Users/..../..../files/Bush1989.02.9.txt
Words: 4821
```

And this repeats for each file in the directory. As you can see, it gives me multiple counts for each file. The files are formatted such as:

> Address on Administration Goals Before a Joint Session of Congress
>
> February 9, 1989
>
> Mr. Speaker, Mr. President, and distinguished Members of the House and
>   Senate...

So, it seems that the script is giving me a count of each "part" of the file, such as the 10 words on the first line, 0 on the line break, 3 on the next, 0 on the next, and then the count for the body of the text.

What I'm looking for is a single count for each file. Any help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: `x = 0` followed by a `x += something` in the same loop makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two lines of your inner loop, which print out the filename and word count, should be part of the outer loop, not the inner loop - as it is, they're being run once per line.

You're also resetting the sentence and word counts for each line - these should be in the outer loop, before the start of the inner loop.

Here's what your code should look like after the changes:

```
import glob

directory = "/Users/.../.../files/*"
output = "/Users/.../.../output.txt"

filepath = glob.glob(directory)

def wordCount(filepath):
    for file in filepath:
        name = file
        fileO = open(file, 'r')
        sentences = 0
        words = 0
        for line in fileO:
            sentences += line.count('.') + line.count('!') + line.count('?')

            tempwords = line.split()
            words += len(tempwords)

        outputO = open(output, "a")
        outputO.write("Name: " + name + "\n" + "Words: " + str(words) + "\n")

wordCount(filepath)
```

Comment: @user1074057: Also you were opening the output file once per input line! The above code opens it once per input file which is still grossly inefficient. Open it ONCE at the start of your code. Further: you count "sentences" but don't write the result.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your identation wrong? I mean, the last lines are called once *per line*, but you really mean once *per file*, don't you?

(besides, try to avoid "file" as an identifier - it is a Python type)